# How do I add items from 2 different listboxes to a single line of a textbox in VisualBasic?

Tags: vb.net

I'm kind of a beginner, and I'm trying to do a program which takes items and their cost (which the user inputs), and it organizes them in two listboxes. An ObjectList and a PriceList. What I'm trying to do is to convert the list box items to a textbox, thus allowing me to save it in a text file (or make it easier at least). This is the code responsible for "textifying" the listboxes.

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
Button3.Click

    For i = 0 To ObjectList.SelectedItems.Count
        RichTextBox1.Clear()
        RichTextBox1.Text &= (ObjectList.Items(i) & " - " & PriceList.Items(i) & vbNewLine)
    Next

End Sub
```

My issue is that the textbox only displays the first row of items.
For example, if the listboxes display Computer and 1000 at row one, and Paper and 3 at row two, it will only show Computer - 1000.

Comment: Basic, VBA, and VB.NET are three different languages. Please don't use redundant tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code:

- You should be using `ObjectList.Items` instead of `ObjectList.SelectedItems`.
- You should be using `.Count - 1` instead of `.Count` because the index of the last item = `Items.Count - 1` (since the first index is 0). Note that `ObjectList.Items(ObjectList.Count)` will throw an `IndexOutOfRangeException`.
- Once you fix the two issues above, you'll be seeing *only* the last row in your textbox, and that's because you're calling `RichTextBox1.Clear()` inside the For loop, forcing `RichTextBox1` to clear its content on each iteration. You should move that line outside (above) the loop.

So, your code should look something like this:

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

    RichTextBox1.Clear()
    For i = 0 To ObjectList.Items.Count - 1
        RichTextBox1.Text &= ObjectList.Items(i) & " - " & PriceList.Items(i) & vbNewLine
    Next

End Sub
```

One last thing: Since you're accessing the items of both `ObjectList` and `PriceList` using the same index, you need to be sure that they have the same number of items.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! And I made it so you can only add an object if you have a price, and vice versa.